# jQuery - Show div depending on mouse position

Tags: jquery

OK, I'm totally stuck...

I have an image inside a hidden div.  I want to only show the image if the mouse's x-coordinates are between 0 and 200 px.

So basically:

```
if pageX <= 200 {
 show div 
} else {
 hide div
}
```

Any advice would be so greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First you have to get mouse position and then check if it's less than 200:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX < 200) {
        $('div').show();
    }
    else {
        $('div').hide();
    }
}
```

**edit:** I'm not checking if it's bigger than zero, because if the mouse is outside the window the handler function will not be triggered

[jQuery's Tutorial: Mouse Position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

Comment: And the award for a total blonde moment goes to...

I have been trying this for hours, including code that was almost identical to yours.  Know what I missed?  The "#" in "#div".

Comment: @user1021567 what's your point? did you name a div like this: <div id="div"></div> ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('div').toggle(e.pageX < 200);
```